# Get JSON value for IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> type

Tags: c#, json, generic-collections

How to get the JSON output only value in C#.

I am trying to use it for type `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<CustomType>>`

I have class with a property of type `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<CustomType>>`

and CustomType is defined as

```
public class CustomType{
    public string Type {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
}

var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collection);

The result i am getting is 

[
    [   
        {"Type":"Role","Value":"RoleA"},
        {"Type":"Role","Value":"RoleB"}
    ],
    [
        {"Type":"Role","Value":"RoleC"}
    ],
    [
        {"Type":"Buyer","Value":"UserA"}
    ],
    [
        {"Type":"Seller","Value":"UserB"}
    ]
]

I need following output
[
    [{"Role" : "RoleA"},{"Role" : "RoleB"}],
    [{"Role" : "RoleC"}],
    [{"Buyer" : "UserA"}]       
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like here,

```
public class CustomType
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> AsJsonProperty()
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {Type, Value}
        };
    }
}

class Class1
{
    public string ToJson(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<CustomType>> customTypes)
    {
        var asJsonFriendly = customTypes.Select(x => x.Select(y => y.AsJsonProperty()));
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(asJsonFriendly);
    }
}
```

When you serialize a dictionary to json, it will be a json object (not array) and keys are going to be property names and values will be property values.

This way is usable especially if your property names contains different characters like {"a property ..": "a value"}

Answer (score 1):

How about converting `CustomType` to a dictionary? (You don't need to change `CustomType` class)

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collection.Select(innerList => 
              innerList.Select(type => new Dictionary<string,object>()
              {
                   {
                        type.Type, type.Value
                   }
              })));
```

Comment: Hi, can this be deserialized back to the custom object?

Answer (score 0):

```
var formatedCollections = collection.Select(c => c.Select(nest => new Dictionary<String,String>(){{nest.Type,nest.Value}})).ToArray();
```

And then Serialize formatedCollection

Comment: Thank you so much. Would it be possible without flatten the arrays

Comment: Then just replace SelectMany with just a Select. Edited my answer

Comment: Replacing with Select not bringing any result.

Comment: Ok Edited and tested. This works. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Thank you. Getting an error saying "An item with the same key has already been added."

Comment: It does not work on dublicate keys. just pick @mecek's answer it's better

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97978/discussion-between-anestis-kivranoglou-and-mukil-deepthi).